# Are there verbs that are neither telic, or atelic?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

These examples from wikipedia are shown as tests to find what is telic, or atelic.

```
Fine: "John built a house in a month."
Bad: *"John built a house for a month."

    → built a house is telic

Bad: *"John built houses in a month."
Fine: "John built houses for a month."
```

I'm wondering if there are verb phrases that fit neither. I've been trying to think of what would be a verb like that, but I'm having no success.

I'm also having trouble figuring this out by reading the article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicity

A related question [What makes progressive verbs different from atelic, and can a verb be both atelic/telic, and/or progressive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/489866/what-makes-progressive-verbs-different-from-atelic-and-can-a-verb-be-both-ateli?noredirect=1#comment1182136_489866)

Comment: I don’t see how any statement can be neither telic nor atelic – that would be equivalent to saying it was neither complete in some sense, nor was it incomplete in some sense. What would it be, then, if neither complete nor incomplete?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Potentially complete?

Comment: I see nothing about those sentences that would make one better or worse than the other. And I certainly don't see how the singularity or plurality has any bearing on that judgment. (I can spend a month building either one house or many houses. And I can do *either* thing *in* a month or *for* a month.)

Comment: This would be a good question for the Linguistics Stack Exchange, since languages other than English incorporate telicity as a grammatical aspect and the argument (if there is one) for being neither telic nor atelic could be examined more overtly. At least in English, I have trouble imagining a verb that isn't either telic or atelic in use, but it's also not a marked part of our grammar.

Comment: @JasonBassford I just don't have any examples that represent the question. I'm hoping for examples. I don't want to assume that those types of forms don't exist just because I can't make them. They could be logically impossible which would fulfill the question, but I have yet to see that argument against those forms being logically possible. And I can't make the arguments myself because I don't know enough.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin I'm hoping this gets answers for english first. I don't want this question to get flooded with information pertaining to other languages. Maybe we can assume it's a general rule later, and perhaps we can move, or duplicate the question on Linguistics for that purpose.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am neither a wife-beater nor a non-wife-beater because I don't have a wife.

Comment: @PeterWone That would make you a non-wife-beater. If you don’t have a wife, you obviously don’t beat your wife.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But he could also be a "potential wife-beater". Though I feel sure he isn't!

Comment: @WS2 He could be a potential _future_ wife-beater, but at the moment of utterance, if he has no wife, then he cannot be a potential wife-beater (assuming we limit the meaning of _wife-beater_ to ‘one who beats his own wife’, of course – he could always go out and beat someone else’s wife, but that seems irrelevant here). Similarly, how can a statement _at the moment of utterance_ and _in the context of the utterance_ be seen as potentially complete?

Comment: After seeing the replies here I thinking that there might be some hypothetical that could be a potential candidate. Like meta discussions about character performances might include verbs that are logical but have no duration. Or verbs used as hyperbole might have no duration, or multiple time frames.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, my comment was largely tongue-in-cheek. But it raises the philosophical question as to whether the appellation "wife-beater", has to be substantively determined, or whether it is an inherent condition which precedes the practice. But I suppose, even were it the former, it would rule out the idea of "potential wife-beater" as illogical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet there are zero elephants on my desk. There is an _infinity_ of things that aren't on my desk, and a smaller infinity of things that _can't_ be on my desk, either because they are incorporeal like software or money, or because like the elephant they won't fit. You might argue that all but the largest and strongest of desks are non-elephant-bearing desks, but this is not an especially useful quality to quantify and so it is not well supported by language in the same way that elephants are not really supported by desks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be difficult to determine the telicity of a verb, but all verbs must be telic or atelic in context.

Imagining a verb that is neither *telic* nor *atelic* is rather like imagining a binary number that is neither 1 nor 0, or imagining an object that is neither tea nor not tea. Because a *telic* aspect indicates that an action or event is complete in some sense, and an *atelic* verb is simply the inverse (an action or event that is incomplete), you're essentially asking if an action or event can be neither complete nor incomplete. I don't think that's possible, as even an indeterminate or ambiguous action/event would have to be one or the other.

However, because *telicity* is partly determined by context (where/how/by whom the sentence is said) and semantics (what the sentence means), the test posed above is flawed for a verb that can take either expression in context. In other words, because the aspect of telicity depends on the noun phrases following the verb, adverbials, tense, and other contextual features, there are verb forms that can be interpreted as telic *or* atelic in the same expression. Take the verb *eat* in the following form:

> I ate.

Telic test:

> I ate in an hour. (Telic - the action was completed in an hour; clearer with a count direct object like *the cake* but still telic here)

Atelic test:

> I ate for an hour. (Atelic - the action went on for an hour without necessarily being completed; clearer with a noncount direct object like *cake* but still atelic here)

Fun alternatives involve adding other expressions or intonations to mean "I already ate," "I just ate," "I ate for a while," and other items to create telic or atelic meanings.

In other words, telicity in English isn't as bounded a grammatical aspect as perfect or progressive aspects. It is not only determined at the verb level or even at the verb phrase level, but also by the semantic interactions between verbs and everything around it.

Nonetheless, every use of a verb is ultimately telic or atelic, in the sense that it will be interpreted to describe either a completed action/event or one still in process.

My main scholarly source for this is Hana Filip in *[Aspect, Eventuality Types, and Nominal Reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=u-rDYQ6GRlsC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=The%20influence%20%20of%20%20noun%20phrase%20semantics%20%20on%20%20the%20%20telicity%20%20of%20%20verbalpredicates%20has%20been%20discussed%20with%20%20respect%20%20to%20%20examples%20%20like%20%20those%20%20in%20%20&source=bl&ots=hKSiNBFjZU&sig=ACfU3U3LWYxc08kw0PttC-Qvc5vfyO8zCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgwY7L14ThAhVKSK0KHf_OBncQ6AEwA3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=aspect%20shift%20is%20traditionally%20accounted%20for&f=false)* (1999). Filip urges moving away from thinking of telicity as an aspect determined on the lexical or phrasal level. While much of the argument is complex, her key claim comes through here:

> Aspect shift  is  traditionally  accounted for  at  the  lexical  level,  in terms of lexical ambiguity.    In  section 3.8.2,  it  has been argued that  *a uniform treatment of aspect shift in terms of  lexical  rule  strategy  is  not viable*,  given  that  lexical  rules  are not  flexible  enough  to  handle  the whole range of phenomena that fall under aspect shift.
>
> Recent   accounts   of   meaning   shifts, discussed above,   treat    the dependency between the  verb  and the adjunct  as  encoded   by   some specification  either  only  on  the  verb  or  only  on  the  adjunct.    There  is yet another way to analyze this dependency:    namely,  v*erbs  (along  with their arguments) and adjuncts are mutually  constraining*,  and  therefore the relevant constraints could  be  stated  over  both  of  them.

...

> The  difference between such  pairs  of  sentences indicates that  it  is  not  an  adjunct  on  its  own  that  determines the  telicity  of  a given sentence.  **It is the inherent lexical  semantics of  the  verb  together with  the  semantics  of  the  adjunct that together determine whether  a sentence will have a telic or an atelic reading**.

Comment: Okay. You've explained the distinction well. If I understand correctly the general rules don't matter so much for telicity. What is more relevant is mostly the contextual usage of the verb. There may be some loose rules like *in*, and *for* usage, but those are not universal. Still all verbs must be telic, or atelic/complete or incomplete. I have a related question here on progressive forms https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/489866/what-makes-progressive-verbs-different-from-atelic-and-can-a-verb-be-both-ateli?noredirect=1#comment1182136_489866

Comment: According to the "Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 120, _The ﬁre destroyed the building_ is a **telic** process

Answer (score 5):

If you understand *telic* to be a description of the utterance in terms of whether it presents a completed act, then the following are *telic* utterances:

> John built a house.
>
> John built the house in only a month.

but depending on what the speaker means to say in context, this could be atelic:

> John was building that house for a year (i.e. when he gave up because he ran out of funds).

or telic:

> John was building that house for a year (it took him so long because he did it alone).

There's nothing morphological there that indicates the difference.

But one could say that "building that house for a year" is atelic in both cases and that the context in the second presents the atelic utterance  *in light of* the now completed act. John was "at it" for a full year in both cases. In the first he ceased (with the house incomplete) and in the second he ceased (with the house completed).

So you might think of atelic verbs as those verbs or verb phrases (including any adverbial modifiers and direct objects) whose action can cease *in media res*.

> She ate the cracker in one bite. <sup>telic</sup>
>
> She was nibbling at the cracker. <sup>atelic</sup>
>
> She nibbled the cracker.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, and examples. I'm also wondering if there can be forms that would be neither telic, or atelic. Some indeterminate form maybe?

Comment: Predications involving a *general* truth or fact are not telic, but I wouldn't consider them atelic either.  *This model gets good gas mileage*  or *She goes to bed late.*

Comment: Oh that's weird. But can we apply some harsh time frame? Like *She goes to bed late while alive*, or *This model gets good gas mileage when in good running condition*. Those are definite time frames, but the ending is indeterminate!

Comment: You should use examples that make sense :)  *She goes to bed late during exam week.*  There's no completed state involved, but it's not the same thing as "was nibbling  a cracker".

Comment: LOL. Yeah ok. Like *She goes to bed late while alive* is a bizarrely redundant, and awkward sentence. And while she's dead will she also be late to bed? I guess if a person was explaining to some other person that she were later a ghost that has the ability to go to bed that might be an exception. :P